# Changing the Caption of an AD-User in the AD-Management Console with VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, properties, ldap, adsi, displayname-attribute

I have a working code for creating a new AD user along with its distinct properties. The only thing I can't get to work is:

The users entry in the AD-Management window (caption) is the same as the CN. But I need the entry to be the same as the DisplayName attribute.

After manually changing the Name of the user entry,  I found out, that the attribute 'name' changed as well. 
(See screenshot)
[Screenshot-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7FFv.png)

So I tried using the attribute 'name' in my code as well.
But when I use the attribute during the first CommitChanges() (effectively creating the entitiy) it doesn't set to the Value I want it to be. Instead it stays the same as the login-name (SAMAccountName) of the user.

If I try to set the Value of the attribute during the later CommitChanges() it throws the following exception

> "00002016: SvcErr: DSID-031A12D2, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM),
>   data 0" & vbLf

Do you have any Ideas what I can do to change the attribute 'name' of an AD-Object?

(BTW: My code contains some german words. Vorname = Given Name / Nachname = Surname etc. in case you're wondering)

```
        Dim o As DirectoryEntry
        Dim c As DirectoryEntries
        Dim OUPath = ("LDAP://OU=" & OU & ",OU=Benutzer,DC=int,DC=xxxx,DC=xx")
        o = New DirectoryEntry(OUPath, "xxxx", "xxxx", System.DirectoryServices.AuthenticationTypes.Secure)
        c = o.Children()
        o = c.Add("CN=" & UsernameV, "user")

        o.Properties("SAMAccountName").Value = UsernameV
        o.Properties("sn").Add(NachnameV)
        o.Properties("givenName").Add(VornameV)
        o.Properties("displayName").Add("" & NachnameV & ", " & VornameV & "")
        o.Properties("name").Add("" & NachnameV & ", " & VornameV & "")
        o.Properties("userPrincipalName").Add(UsernameV & "@xxxx")
        o.CommitChanges()
        o.Invoke("setPassword", New Object() {PWV})
        o.CommitChanges()
        'newUser.Properties("userAccountControl").Add(512)
        'newUser.CommitChanges()
        o.Properties("description").Add(UsernameV)
        o.Properties("scriptPath").Add("logon.bat")
        o.Properties("homeDrive").Add("H:")
        o.Properties("homeDirectory").Add("\\datsrv-01\homes\" & UsernameV & "$")
        o.Properties("company").Add(ComboBox_so.SelectedItem.ToString)
        o.Properties("department").Add(ComboBox_abt.SelectedItem.ToString)
        o.Properties("telephoneNumber").Add(TelV)
        o.Properties("userAccountControl").Value = 65536
        o.CommitChanges()
        o.NativeObject.AccountDisabled = False
        o.CommitChanges()
        MsgBox("Erstellen erfolgreich")
```

Comment: I may be missing something here, but changing the `.Text` property of the form to the same text as the "Display name" property should sort this?

Comment: using the syntax o.Properties("name").Text gives me an Error: "Text" Not a Memeber of PropertyValueCollection

Comment: Oh okay. Now I get what you mean. But that, unfortunately, also won't change much, because I can't set the attribute manually. It always gets copied from the SAMAccountName-attribute.